# Order of files in a FileSet (phing)

Tags: phing, fileset

Is it possible to get the files from a phing FileSet in a specific order (0-9 followed by A-Z for example)? Right now it is taking my numbered files in a completely random order.

```
<fileset dir="${mydirectory}">
    <include name="*" />
</fileset>
```

Comment: No, you can't do that within the fileset. What do you need it for?

Comment: I need it to concatenate CSS and JavaScript files in a certain order in my build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<exec command="cd ${mydirectory}/ &amp;&amp; echo *" escape="false" outputProperty="myfiles" />
<append destfile="concatenated.txt">
    <filelist dir="${mydirectory}" files="${myfiles}" />
</append>
```